# persistent pointer to vector element in place of 'this'

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I need persistent pointers to elements of `std::vector`. Straightforward `this` won't do, as demonstrated here:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(int i)
        : my_i(i)
        , whoAmI([this]()->void{ std::cout<<"I am class A with i="<<my_i<<std::endl; })
        {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    int my_i;
    std::function<void()> whoAmI;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    std::cout << "Initialization:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(A(i));
        vec.back().whoAmI();
    }
    std::cout << "Retrieval:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        vec.at(i).whoAmI();
}
```

Which yields

```
Initialization:
I am class A with i=0
I am class A with i=1
I am class A with i=2
Retrieval:
I am class A with i=2
I am class A with i=2
I am class A with i=2
```

whereas I need

```
Retrieval:
I am class A with i=0
I am class A with i=1
I am class A with i=2
```

Of course, in this example one could easily work around. In real life, the persistent pointer shall be passed to `Qt::connect`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but I suspect [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) may solve it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sounds like a pretty heavyweight solution. But on second thought, maybe the best.

Comment: Surprised this didn't fault, as the capture of `this` and saving it in the `std::function` is invalided when the vector has to reallocate.

Comment: @Richard Critten It does not even fault if the loop limit is set to a million instead of 3.

Comment: Could You show example closer to Your problem? In the imaginable casese for me there is no problem with coming up with very simple solution

Comment: There is really no solution, as vector elements are moved all the time and can even be deallocated when vector expands. The closest thing to a solution is having a vector of pointers. Another possibility is to use `list`.

Comment: What do you mean by _persistent pointers_?

Comment: @Arkadiy Vector of pointers... I fear I have to go for that. Let's see whether somebody comes up with another idea, though.

Comment: @bartop, @Ron: I need to `connect(SignalSource, Signal, [this](){...})` with `this` replaced by something that does not dangle after `*this` was relocated in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of `std::vector<A>` cannot be set without involving the move constructor `A(A&&)`. After a move, the old `this` is dangling. Let's call it the move-this problem.

Also, vector element addresses may change as the vector grows. This problem can be solved either by reserving a sufficient vector size, or by encapsulating the vector elements in unique pointers. However, none of these measures solves the move-this problem, which therefore is the more fundamental one.

There are several solutions to the move-this problem:

- Instead of using `this`, capture the owning vector and the vector index (see solution by @bartop)
- Update the lambda expression in the move constructor (see solutions by @Jack and @KillzoneKid)
- Instead of initializing the lambda expression in the regular constructor, and updating it in the move constructor, insert a separate `init` function:

```
class A {
    ...
    A(int i) : my_i(i) {}
 /* A(A&&) = default; */
    void init();
    ...
};

void A::init() {
    whoAmI = [this]()->void{ std::cout<<"I am class A with i="<<my_i<<std::endl; };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    std::cout << "Initialization:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(A(i));
        vec.back().init();
        vec.back().whoAmI();
    }
    ...
}
```

However, after some more days of experimentation with my `QObject::connect` application, I came to the conclusion that it is far better to **avoid** the entire problem by moving the concerned logic to the parent class (in the minimal example shown here: to `main`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try capturing indexes by value like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


class A {
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(int i, std::vector<A> &vec)
        : whoAmI([i, &vec]()->void{
             std::cout<<"I am class A with i="<< i << ". Calling whoAmI(): "  << std::endl;
             vec[i];
        })
        {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    std::function<void()> whoAmI;


};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    std::cout << "Initialization:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(A(i, vec));
        vec.back().whoAmI();
    }
    std::cout << "Retrieval:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        vec.at(i).whoAmI();
}
```

Comment: Won't help when it comes to `Qt::connect` ... except if I access some global variable to access `vec` in order to access `vec[i]`.

Comment: @JoachimW You can additionaly store reference/shared_ptr to the vector in the lambda. This will make it usable, right?

Comment: @JoachimW Now `A` should work as persistent pointer. Even though I do not know what it is for ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding this at inizialization site of your lambda, so this is not going to work in in any circumstance the object is moved or copied indeed.

A possible solution could be to add a level of indirection:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A;
class fuction_wrapper
{
public:
  A* ref;
  std::function<void(A*)> lambda;
  void operator()() const { lambda(ref); }
};

class A {
public:
  A() = delete;
  A(int i)
  : my_i(i)
  , whoAmI({this, [] (A* a) { std::cout<<"I am class A with i="<< a->my_i << std::endl; }})
  {}
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A(A&& a)
  {
    my_i = std::move(a.my_i);
    whoAmI = { this, std::move(a.whoAmI.lambda) };
  }

  int my_i;
  fuction_wrapper whoAmI;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> vec;
  std::cout << "Initialization:" << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(A(i));
    vec.back().whoAmI();
  }
  std::cout << "Retrieval:" << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    vec.at(i).whoAmI();
}
```

Probably not the most eye-candy solution available but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine your lambda inside the move constructor, so that it gets an updated `this` after the move, since the temporary `A(i)` you push in is no more.

```
A(A&& a) 
    { 
        this->my_i = a.my_i; 
        this->whoAmI = [this]()->void { std::cout << "I am class A with i=" << this->my_i << std::endl; }; 
    };
```

https://ideone.com/s5ZyS5

```
Initialization:
I am class A with i=0
I am class A with i=1
I am class A with i=2
Retrieval:
I am class A with i=0
I am class A with i=1
I am class A with i=2
```

Comment: Redefining the lambda is specific to the toy example. However, I guess your solution could be easily modified so that one updates not the lambda, but a pointer that replaces `this`.